Distance measurement error in object detection in python
the distance being calculated by the system developed is incorrect and not even accurate. Learning and researching online I encountered many issues but sorted one after the other but can't find a solution for this.
TRIG_PIN = 29  # GPIO 17
ECHO_PIN = 31  # GPIO 27
GPIO.setup(TRIG_PIN, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(ECHO_PIN, GPIO.IN)
engine = pyttsx3.init()
net = cv2.dnn.readNet("yolov3-tiny.weights", "yolov3-tiny.cfg")
classes = []
OBJECT_REAL_SIZE = 20  
OBJECT_PERSON_DISTANCE = 30  
def ultrasonic_distance():
    GPIO.output(TRIG_PIN, True)
    time.sleep(0.00001)
    GPIO.output(TRIG_PIN, False)
    start_time = time.time()
    end_time = time.time()
    while GPIO.input(ECHO_PIN) == 0:
        start_time = time.time()
    while GPIO.input(ECHO_PIN) == 1:
        end_time = time.time()
    pulse_duration = end_time - start_time
    distance = pulse_duration * 17150  # Speed of sound is 343 meters per second
    return round(distance, 2)
def calculate_distance(object_size_pixels):
    distance = (OBJECT_REAL_SIZE * OBJECT_PERSON_DISTANCE) / object_size_pixels
    return round(distance, 2)
'''
Is it an issue in the code which I didn't notice or any problem with the ultrasonic sensor I'm using?

The object was detected and recognized but the distance measurement is incorrect. Even if the distance is around 100cm it says 5cm for eg.

